# C SegFault fixed by print?

Tags: c, pointers, segmentation-fault

I have the task to write a program in C. The program should be able to check for parameters and create arrays that are as big as the parameter I gave. I have to fill the array with random numbers. Works fine so far. Later on my task is to sort the array using pointers. First thing is I did not quite understand how pointers work but I made the sorting work so far. The only problem is, that I can only sort to a size of 4. If my parameter is bigger than 4 I get the first 4 numbers sorted and then a Segmentation fault. I cannot find the issue but the fun part is, that if I add a printf just to print my parameter again it works fine for any parameter I want! I do not know what is happening!

Here is the exact task again, because I think I didn't describe it that well:

> To do this, create a dynamic pointer field of the same size and initialize it with pointers to the elements of the int field. When sorting, the pointers should now be sorted so that the first pointer points to the smallest int value, the second to the next largest value, and so on.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    
    int *array;
    int **arrpointer;
    
    int size = atoi(argv[1]);
     
    if (size == 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Wrong parameter!\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    //printf("Array-Size : ");   //First I had it with scanf, which works perfectly fine without a print
    //scanf("%d", &size);

    printf("Input%d", size);  //This is the print I need somehow!

    // allocate memory
    array = (int *)malloc(size * sizeof(int));        // Init Array
    arrpointer = (int **)malloc(size * sizeof(int));  // Init Pointer Array

    //Check Pointer array 
    if (arrpointer != NULL) {
        printf("Memory allocated\n\n");
    } else {
        fprintf(stderr, "\nNo free memory.\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    
    if (array != NULL) {
        printf("Memory is allocated\n\n");

        //Fill Array
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            array[i] = rand() % 1000; //I know it is not random right now, will add later
            int *temp = &array[i];
            arrpointer[i] = temp;     //Pointer fill
        } 
    } else {
        fprintf(stderr, "\nNo free memory to allocate.\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    shakersort(arrpointer, size);  //Function to sort pointers
    zeigeFeld(arrpointer, size);  //Function to Print
        
    free(array);
    free(arrpointer);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

I know its a bit confusing, I am sorry.
I will also add the code where I sort it below.

```
void swap(int **a, int **b) {

    int ram;
    ram = **a;
    **a = **b;
    **b = ram;
}

void shakersort(int **a, int n) {
    int p, i;
    for (p = 1; p <= n / 2; p++) {
        for (i = p - 1; i < n - p; i++)
            if (*a[i] > *a[i+1]) {
                swap(&a[i], &a[i + 1]);
            }
           
        for (i = n - p - 1; i >= p; i--)
            if (*a[i] < *a[i-1]) {
                swap(&a[i], &a[i - 1]);                
            }           
    }
}
```

This is the code I tried to build for the pointers and it works fine so far.

I hope someone can help or give some input to why my print fixes the problem. I really dont understand!
Thank you for your time and help, let me know if I should add anything!

Comment: There are two things that come to my mind: first, `arrpointer` should be initialized with `arrpointer = (int **) malloc(size * sizeof(int*));`. You should use the size of an int pointer, not of an int. Second, in my understanding your task is not to sort the actual int array (what is what you are trying to do) but to sort the _pointer arrary_ so that the original int array is unchanged but the pointers in your `arrpointer` are sorted.

Comment: Also, you should look over the snippets you posted again: in the first one the last curly bracket should be after `return EXIT_FAILURE;` and not at the and. In the second one the signature of your swap method is missing. It would be easier to follow if you corrected this :)

Comment: @Kebberling [Instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67313467/c-segfault-fixed-by-print#comment118981189_67313467) of the unneeded cast, and potential type mismatch, `arrpointer = malloc(sizeof *arrpointer * size);` is easier to code right, review and maintain.

Comment: You're right, didn't know of that syntax

Comment: @Kebberling I corrected my post, thanks for the information, had problems formatting. Second, you are right, I have to sort the pointer array, I thought I did but I just checked and it is not the case. Any tipps how to change it to sort the pointers?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica I used your method and it works fine without a print! That was my mistake! Thank you. Do I need to do the same for my array or does it safely work there like I did?

Comment: @snakezz `array = (int *) malloc(size * sizeof(int));` is OK today but is harder to review than `array = malloc(sizeof *array * size);`.  Later if  code became `long long *array`, `sizeof(int)` would be wrong.  Using `array = malloc(sizeof *array * size);` is right today and after that type update.   `array = (int *) malloc(size * sizeof(int));` is [WET](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself#DRY_vs_WET_solutions).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The program has undefined behavior because the allocation size is incorrect for the array:

```
arrpointer = (int **)malloc(size * sizeof(int));
```

allocates space for `size` integers, but it should allocate space for `size` pointers to `int`, which on 64-bit systems are larger than `int`. Use this instead:

```
arrpointer = (int **)malloc(size * sizeof(int *));
```

Or use the type of the destination pointer:

```
arrpointer = malloc(sizeof(*arrpointer) * size);
```

This latter syntax is much safer as it works for any non `void` pointer type.

Note however that this array of pointers is overkill for your purpose. You should just implement the sorting functions on arrays of `int`:

```
void swap(int *a, int *b) {
    int ram = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = ram;
}

void shakersort(int *a, int n) {
    int p, i;
    for (p = 1; p <= n / 2; p++) {
        for (i = p - 1; i < n - p; i++) {
            if (a[i] > a[i + 1]) {
                swap(&a[i], &a[i + 1]);
            }
        }
        for (i = n - p - 1; i >= p; i--) {
            if (a[i] < a[i - 1]) {
                swap(&a[i], &a[i - 1]);                
            }
        }          
    }
}
```

Whether the above code actually sorts the array is unclear to me, I never use shakersort.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! Will check if everything works from now on and try your solutions!

Comment: Minor aside: `size * sizeof(*arrpointer)` works well with/without `()` - style issue.  It also works well as `sizeof(*arrpointer) * size` as multiplication is communicative.  Yet leading the calculation with `size_t` instead of `int` helps with more complex ones like `size_t * int * int` that do not overflow whereas `int * int * size_t` might overflow the `int * int` part.

Comment: Just for my information, what sorting algorithm do you use mostly? I know, that it is overkill, would never do it like that if my Professor wouldnt want me to!  In what cases would I use something like that? Have you got an example for me?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica: I agree with you 100% about the potential overflow issue, but I prefer to use the extra parentheses when the expression is non-trivial, especially if it involves `*` as both a dereferencing operator and a multiplication operator.  My style choice is to insert spaces around binary operators and not between unary operators and their operand: `sizeof *arrpointer` breaks this rule, `sizeof*arrpointer` looks bad and `sizeof(*arrpointer)` is a very common idiom that does not break my rule.

Comment: @snakezz: I use `mergesort` or the C library `qsort`, which may use a modified version of quicksort or something else. `mergesort` is stable, which may be a requirement. If the sorting phase is a performance bottleneck, TimSort might be a better approach or a specialized algorithm such as radixsort for integers.

Answer (score 0):

why do you use pointers before printf??
first you need to know what the pointer is:
the pointer is some kind of variable that contains address of some another variable.

for example:

int b = 2;

int * a = &b;

a variable include the address of variable b. then if you print ((a)) it will give you hex number which is the address of b. if you print ((*a)), compiler will print what in the address that int the variable a and print the amount of number in address of cell b(that means 2).

now i guess you understand what the pointer is, look again at your code and correct the mistakes.

Comment: I guess the stars around the printf aren't pointers but a misleading try of highlighting the questionable passage using markdown syntax

Comment: I tried to highlight that line of code, will delete it. Thank you for your explanation, will look over it again with that knowledge!

Answer (score 0):

I updated my code from

```
arrpointer = (int **) malloc(size * sizeof(int));
```

to

```
arrpointer = malloc(sizeof *arrpointer * size);
```

And it works fine!
Thank you all for your help!